# In NixOS, is there a way to get a list of available console fonts?

Tags: nixos

I'd like to find a list of available fonts that I could use in an expression like:

```
{
  i18n = {
    consoleFont = "font-name-here";
  };
}
```

in my configuration.nix. (In particular, I'm looking for one with a high DPI, so that I can read it on my machine, but just a list of them would do nicely.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This took me forever to figure out, but I eventually did `nix-locate Lat2-Terminus16` and found the `/share/consolefonts` directory, where I was then able to list the available console fonts.

Comment: @AleXoundOS `nix-locate` is provided by the `nix-index` package.

Comment: How does one decide which font to use?

Answer (score -2):

It's not in the old location, so I suggest:

```bash
ls /etc/static/kbd/consolefonts/ | grep .psfu.gz
```